# Purchase ad by selecting the time slot in broadcast queue in iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ads

I have a requirement like this,

1. User goes to ad section in the app where all ads are displayed in the table. He will select which ad needs to be shown in the broadcast queue and at what time. The ad needs to be purchased before inserting into the queue.
2. The queue is a series of audio objects which are broadcasted the user. this is similar to radio.

Could someone tell me how should I go with ad purchase implementation in the app? Should I need to go with in-app purchase or via 3rd pardy payment option like paypal etc. Please provide some inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an 'Ad' that you are selling is a digital good, you must use Apple in-app purchase system. That is a requirement by Apple.

You can use Paypal API (or any other payment gateway) only for purchases of physical goods. And charity donations.

[Here's a link that describes it in detail.](http://www.absoluteripple.com/1/post/2012/02/apples-in-app-purchase-when-do-we-have-to-use-it.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have you seen any apps that have this kind of functionality?

Comment: An ad selling app? Not that I know of.

Comment: Can end user select the ad and add it the broadcast queue? I never seen in any of the app where ads can be selected. Since this concept is still under finalization, I would like to have more inputs on this.

Thanks,

Comment: That would be hard to answer. What exactly do you mean by a broadcast queue? Is it like facebook ad system, only on mobile? Where are the ads being broadcasted to? What is the end user? What is the aim of your app? If you are making a google ads/facebook ads clone, sure. Its possible because its already being done by Google and Facebook, right?

Comment: Broadcast queue is nothing like a queue of audio stream, every logged in user can broadcast a audio, this will be added to the queue and every one will be listening to the queue. Also there will be option for the user to add ad into the queue, these ads are audio ad where user can choose the time slot in the queue that when it has to be played. The user (logged in user) can add the audio ad by purchasing the same. For this we need payment gateway.But I am not sure whether we need to go for 3rd party payment option of in-app purchase. Its all confusion.

Comment: Also in-app purchase cannot be used because there is one more requirement where user can have ad with text template, this text template is editable (short message). This message will be displayed when ad is broadcasted. So how this can be done via in-app purchase?

Comment: That can be done simply by first allowing the user to purchase the ad. Once purchased, store this fact somewhere, prompt the user with your text template. Publish it after that.

Comment: But can I mix the contents of web and app during in-app purchase? I mean once I select a product, I will ask user to do record audio, after that redirect the user to slot page in webveiew where user can select time slot for broadcast, once it is done, payment is processed in the app via in-app purchase. Will this works?